# How to display currently connected users/workstations to a Windows SMB Share?

Tags: windows, network-shares, smb

I'am just looking for a way to view the currently connected peers to a Windows SMB share?

For example: I want now to see who is connected to the Windows server and is he doing any file transfers?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/581219/1030702) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a command prompt run `net session`. That will show you session connection information. It will not show you who is actively transferring data. For that you'll need to run a packet capture program on the server.

You could also run the MMC console relative to the Windows OS and Role for File sharing (Share and Storage Management in Windows Server 2008 R2 for instance). For instance, On Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 you could open the Computer Management console and navigate to `File Services|Share and Storage Management` and click the `Manage Sessions` item or the `Manage Open Files` item in the Action Pane.

---

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second paragraph, with more specific steps or screenshots if possible? Back when I was looking this up, I did find [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581219/find-out-who-is-locking-a-file-on-a-network-share#comment19315492_1554071), but it did not work on Server 2012 (the Computer Management method does work).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I just can't seem to find that on 2012 for some reason - perhaps they moved or removed it, or perhaps I'm just being stupid. Ah well.

Answer (score 18):

There are two basic ways to see which files on SMB shares are being accessed:

- [CLI] The `openfiles` command.
- [GUI] The `Open Files` object under `Computer Management` (`compmgmt.msc`) => `Shared Folders` => `Open Files`.

  [image: Screenshot of Computer Management]

Any file that is currently open should be considered to be potentially in use, either being read, written to, or simply held open by a process on a client computer.

These will also show you which user (or computer, if there's no user associated with it) owns the handle. Otherwise, see [joeqwerty's answer](https://superuser.com/a/783957/117590) for how to grab just a list of active SMB sessions/users.

Comment: Or Start > right click on Computer > Manage

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to query on a remote server:

PS C:\Users\adminrudy> invoke-command -ComputerName SERVER-01 -ScriptBlock {net session}