# Log of devices connected to a Windows 10 shared folder

Tags: windows-10, login, shared-folders, smb

I have a shared folder on my computer and I'm connected to a local network.
Is there a way to know who has connected to my shared folder in local network?
Does Windows keep a log of the connected devices (name, ip, time...)?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer to a similar question help? https://superuser.com/a/783961/1128831